# configure openshift online Kibana to view archived logs

Tags: openshift, openshift-online

**Update** kibana works without any effort deploying the  python catalogue template a starter cluster and on "pro-us-east-1". Its broken on "pro-eu-west-1" for old and new projects and using the templates seen to work elsewhere.

**Update**: Here is a screen recording of the problem https://www.useloom.com/share/70469210881a46b69a1914462f8cc7ad

I have setup a process on OpenShift Online Pro using the official `openshift/php:7.0`. The health check is running so it is logging:

10.131.30.1 - - [08/Apr/2018:16:33:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1023 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
10.131.30.1 - - [08/Apr/2018:16:33:53 +0000] "GET /health.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"

If I click on "View Archive" it takes me to a Kibana 4.6.4 dashboard. I see a "Warning No default index pattern." The Kibana documentation and prior experience tells me that Kibana should let me browse the fields to configure the indexing. Poking around I haven't been able to get any data to show on Kibana and it seems that there isn't any data being found in elastic search or that Kibana isn't connected to the correct log index. How do I bootstrap this? Thanks!

To reproduce on openshift online pro:

1. go to the catalogue. Select "PHP" then "Laravel + MySQL (Persistent)"
2. simply accept all the defaults
3. run `ab -c 5 -n 50000 <route>` to try to force a flush to kibana

I tried the same steps on OpenShift Online Starter and Kibana gives the same `Warning No default index pattern. You must select or create one to continue.`

**Update:**

On one cluster `logs.pro-us-east-1.openshift.com` Kibana doesn't load with a JavaScript error. It should be showing a project called `tiller` but Kibana crashes out with an error referring to a different openshift project `legalknowledge`. Here is a screenshot where the top left it shows the demo project name created using the above steps `laravel-mysql-persistent` yet the browser javascript error is talking about a elastic index for a deleted project `id: project.legalknowledge.e60761e4-3b39-11e8-b27b-12b5519f9b58.*`   https://www.dropbox.com/s/0pcgu5yhsw2yi8m/wrong-project-openshift.png?dl=0

**Update**: same problem on eu-west cluster where it gives the js error but has the correct project name.

Comment: Which Pro cluster are you using?

Comment: `oc project` shows  `Using project "tiller" on server "https://api.pro-us-east-1.openshift.com:443".` The pod in question is `po/laravel-mysql-persistent-1-p9l9l`.

Comment: The one time I saw data on Kibana (haven't been able to repeat it) I saw an elastic search index name in the format `project.${namespace}.guid` it was in a test oc project `logs` so it was something like `project.logs.ae1cd5bf...`. Most other time with my custom s2i it asks me to specify a default index (none exists) and shows an index name `project.emptyproject`. With the `openshift/php:7.0` s2i and demo code Kibana only loads the top menu bar and is blank (on both chrome and safari)

Comment: same issue using a free starter account on the Canadian cluster with the same built-in laravel template and all the defaults running at`http://bbb1-aaa1.193b.starter-ca-central-1.openshiftapps.com`. i have updated the question with this information.

Comment: I haven't got complete confirmation of what specific issues there may, but yes, the Online clusters are having some issues with aggregated logging at the moment. There will be some upgrades in a couple of weeks which may help address them. For now it would seem that you might not want to rely on the aggregated logging feature.

Comment: I have raised a support case CASE 02074182.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upshot was that the cluster admins had to delete some old elastic search indexes and provision more space.

So the technical answer is that you shouldn’t need to do anything to get “view archive” working and should raise a support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT*** This doesn't actually appear to be a fix the problem seems to be on a particular cluster. Keeping this answer as blank for the comments.

Comment: Are you trying to use your own PHP image rather than the PHP S2I builder that OpenShift provides?

Comment: yes this is an nginx with php-fpm image at https://github.com/UniqKey/s2i-nginx-php7-container

Comment: i am down this rabbithole as the devs started out with nginx doing rewrite rules fronting php. so i may well now just upgrade to the standard image then recreate the nginx rewrite rules as `.htaccess` mod_rewrite rules in the official template. never the less since i am down a rabbithole of trying to tweak a custom s2i (and have done custom s2i in the past for things like `R` shiny framework) I am wanting to bottom this out.

Comment: All I can suggest is that everywhere you need to log anything, use ``/proc/1/fd/1``. Do not send to a log file and then try and tail it. Also never log to the stdout/stderr of the current process if that is not actually process ID 1. So don't use ``/proc/self/fd/2`` and don't use ``/tmp/error.log``. Always log direct to stdout of process ID 1 using ``/proc/1/fd/1``.

Comment: Redirecting to `/proc/1/fd/1` is working. Going to leave it a while then see whether it flows.

Comment: Redirect? Or do you mean changing the nginx and php-fm config files to log there instead if where they were?

Comment: apologies sloppy use of language. i used search and replace in config files to set `access.log = /proc/1/fd/1`, and `slowlog = /proc/1/fd/1`, and `php_admin_value[error_log] = /proc/1/fd/1`,

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I have run up an official 7.0 image using the service catalogue and its demo code. Same problem. I have edited the question to reflect that kibana shows no data with the official php:7.0 image and an official templates sample code.